# Is it possible to get requested URL without Javascript

Tags: html

I have a page that uses Javascript to load some content.

I would like to forward to another page (But keeping the URL parameters) if the user does not have javascript enabled.

I can use the following to forward

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://testurl.com" />
</noscript>
```

But I have to hardcode the URL. Is it possible to retrieve the requested URL (and parameters) without the use of javascript, or server-side code (I dont have access to server code).

I am looking for a non javascript equivalent to "window.location.search", if such a thing exists.

Comment: What do you mean with "retrieve the requested URL" and from where do you want to request something. Also, who should "receive" this URL?

Comment: No, nor would I want there to be. Imagine a site was able to redirect any request for http://example.com/?user=me@example.com to http://malwaresite.com/?user=me@example.com just by modifying an HTML file. Security nightmare. Some browsers are even blocking `http-equiv="refresh"` because of security issues...

Comment: @heretic I understand that concern. But it seems you could already do this pretty easily with Javascript?

Comment: But I can easily disable JavaScript in my browser. Can't disable HTML.